# Is Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() the appropriate choice for running a task that I need to timeout?

Tags: java, concurrency

We are unfortunately stuck for the medium term with having to call a method that can sometimes never return, and forever freeze the thread that called it.  Fortunately that actual call interacts with little else in the system, and returns no value.  So we're thinking that until we can fix the offending code, we need to run the invocation in a separate thread that we can monitor and interrupt if it exceeds a timeout.

Clearly smarter people than I have already solved this problem and left their gifts in the concurrent package, and since this will be my first use of anything in the concurrent package, I'd just like to confirm that I'm picking the best approach.

So I'm thinking I'd get an ExecutorService by calling Excutors.newSingleThreadExecutor, submit a Runnable to it, and then call the overload of Future.get() that accepts a timeout as a parameter.

The actual task to perform is just to call a single void method on an object that I can pass into the constructor of the Runnable.

If this is the right approach, or close, I'd also really appreciate a short code sample if you're feeling generous with your time.  :)

Thanks

Comment: It is the right approach if the task reacts to the interruption by stopping what it is doing - if it doesn't your thread will stay alive...

Answer (score 4):

> Clearly smarter people than I have already solved this problem

Actually its not really solved IMHO.

To interrupt a task it has to be well behaved and check the interrupt or it won't actually stop.  However, if its well behaved its unlikely to need to be killed in the first place.

You can use the deprecated `Thread.stop()` if you are sure there is no possible side effects. This requires using a plain Thread. Its not ideal even if you "know" this shouldn't cause a problem and again using a flag to stop the task is preferred.

Comment: +1 I agree with you entirely.  I'd put money that there's no flag in this process, though.  Otherwise, why would OP be asking? :)

Comment: @ErickRobertson Unfortunately, those are your only two options. Either the long-running process explicitly supports "clean" time-outs internally like sockets do, or it doesn't. If it doesn't, your only choice is to crash the thread, there's no other way in Java to time-out a method execution. You can try to mitigate the damage by using the overload that raises an exception and doing some cleanup by catching it in the thread, but it's impossible to tell, in general, whether this is a good idea.

Comment: We do actually want to "crash" the thread.  Will Future.get kill the thread after the supplied timeout has passed, or does it just return null and the thread is still running? There appear to be other methods in the neighborhood of ExecutorService that will help me implement hard timeouts... is one of those a better choice?

Comment: Future#get will throw a TimeoutException after the timeout and the thread will continue running.

Comment: If you need a hard timeout, your only option is to run a `new Thread` which you join and if this times out, stop() the thread.